# Remove characters from specific length

Tags: shell, awk, sed

How can I remove the set of characters from a specified length in a file using shell script.
Example:

Filename : `abc.txt`

```
helloshell
```

Now how can I remove characters starting from 8 to 10 (the `ell` at the end)?

I have tried `sed -r` command on Linux servers but it's not working on AIX servers.

Linux command:

```
sed -r 's/.(.{3}).*/\1/' filename.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you tried?  What went wrong?  Please show what you've attempted and what you get and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Show the `sed -r` command you used on Linux.  Welcome to the world of portability.  GNU `sed` provides more functionality than AIX `sed`, which hews close to what POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) provides.  When we see what you used with GNU `sed`, the conversion to AIX `sed` may be straight-forward (possibly using `\{` in place of `{`, etc).  BUT: we can't help you if you don't show us the code you used!

Comment: And while you're considering how to improve your question, please also have a quick look at the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) description. You've asked a very specific question that probably has an answer, but is it the answer you need? Tell us what underlying problem you're trying to solve -- there may be a better way!

Comment: The direct transliteration of the `sed` command you show is `sed 's/.\(.\{3\}\).*/\1/' filename.txt`, but that extracts characters 2-4 from the line, not 8-10, so I'm not sure what you're up to.  Maybe you should show us 5 lines of input and the 5 lines of expected output.  However, the GNU `sed` `-r` option means you don't have to use backslashes before `(){}` in your regexes when they're used for grouping and counting — and you need to add those backslashes when you use a different version of `sed` (or you use a different option in place of `-r`; it's `-E` on BSD or Mac OS X, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/^(.{7}).{0,3}(.*)$/\1\2/g'
helloshell
hellosh
1234567890
1234567
$
```

`{0,3}` ensures 3 or less chars from 8th position (0,3 implies remove only if present and hence also removes 1/2/3 chars from 8th position) i.e match and remove minimum 0 chars(for no chars) and maximum 3 chars

If you want exactly only 3 chars to removed from 8th position use `{3}` but it wont remove chars from 8th position if there are less than 3 chars, eg:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(.{7}).{3}(.*)$/\1\2/g'
123456789
123456789
$
```

Edit1:

you can use this instead without the -r switch and some escaping: `sed 's/^\(.\{7\}\).\{0,3\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g'`

for performing the above operation only lines starting with `BH`, you can add a restriction for the substitute command like this:

`sed '/^BH/s/^\(.\{7\}\).\{0,3\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g'`

`/^BH/s..` would ensure substitution is performed only on lines starting with `BH`

```
$ sed '/^BH/s/^\(.\{7\}\).\{0,3\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g'
BHhelloshell
BHhelloll
BH123456789
BH123459
helloshell
helloshell
$
```

To exclude `BH` while counting you can use:

```
$ sed '/^BH/s/^BH\(.\{7\}\).\{0,3\}\(.*\)$/BH\1\2/g'
BHhelloshell
BHhellosh
BH123456789
BH1234567
helloshell
helloshell
$
```

Comment: use `-E` instead if you are on Mac

Comment: i am using aix machine

Comment: @PuneetGupta you can use this instead without the `-r` switch and some escaping: `sed 's/^\(.\{7\}\).\{0,3\}\(.*\)$/\1\2/g'`

Comment: `\1\2` are back references to captured groups `(.{7}).{3}(.*)`

Comment: one more favour required please: i want to remove characters in selected lines in a file like lines starting with BH character should remove the characters from 8 to 10. Means I want to modify the file in which multiple lines exists but want to remove characters of lines starting with **BH** characters

Answer (score 1):

With Bash (extract substring from 0 to 7th character):

```
str="helloshell"
echo ${str:0:7}
```

With sed (removes 3 characters starting from 7th position) :

```
str="helloshell"
startpos=7;
nbchar=3;
echo "$str" | sed "s/^\(.\{$startpos\}\).\{$nbchar\}\(.*\)/\1\2/"
```

Comment: With POSIX shell (more likely in use on AIX) you could also use `echo ${str%???}`. But we still don't have code from the fellow asking the question, so ALL answers are premature. We can't help him fix his code if we haven't seen his code.

Comment: sed: 0602-404 Function s/^\(.\{\}\).\{\}\(.*\)/\1\2/ cannot be parsed.

Comment: @ghoti - this is what I want and I believe that question is clear enough to understand. Kindly provide resolution

Comment: @ghoti A POSIX compliant sed command should work, even if it's not the optimum response due to unknown variables.

Comment: @PuneetGupta If you have some `/` in your replacement strings, try another separator, eg. pipe char : `̀sed "s|^\(.\{$start\}\).\{$end\}\(.*\)|\1\2|"`

Comment: @Kenavoz i dont have any / in replacement but still facing the cannot be parsed exception

Comment: Fixed typo in var names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are always expecting the last 3 to be deleted.

```
echo helloshell | sed 's/...$//'
```

For 8-10 try this:

```
echo helloshell | sed 's/\(.\{7\}\).../\1/'
echo helloshellHowAreYou | sed 's/\(.\{7\}\).../\1/'
```

For AIX you may need to remove the `\` from `\{`

```
sed 's/\(.{7}\).../\1/'
```

And if there is a pattern that you want in the search string you have to adjust the value within in the `\(` and `\)`

Comment: can we make ... Dynamic. Because if i have to remove 10 characters then have to put 10 dots. Please suggest

Comment: it could be `s/\(.{7}\).{3}/\1/` you can replace the 3 with any arbitrary number.